# Trying to order quality PCB with edge connector / gold fingers

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I am not an expert, and maybe even specialist, in PCBs and the ways they are made. Was ordering PCBs for 5 years from single supplier in China, was relatively happy about pricing and quality. However had problems with foreign objects in FR4 material, some shortages, and bad silkscreen, but in overall all the assembled boards work properly (I assemble manually).

My previous designs are FR4, 1.6 mm thickness, green mask, white silkscreen, 0.4 mm drills, and ENIG finishing of the board and edge connector - must be nothing very special.

I've learnt, empirically, that ENIG for edge connector is a bad idea as the gold is easily being scraped away leaving copper (or nickel) stripped.

I recently made a new design, and, to my surprise, my usual contact refused to make them saying "not this time" and "go to another manufacturer" - without any further details what is wrong.

I selected surface finish ENIG of 2u" and gold fingers (total area of 66x7.6 mm) of au:10u"/ni:120u".

Having contacted several well known PCB producers I see they go wild - quoting up to $41 per board (for 150x60 mm design and gold fingers of 66x7.6 mm), literally putting 30 grams of the pure gold onto the set of 50 boards. Sounds like I am going to buy jewelry, not a PCBs.

I have read that it is recommended to have 25u" of plated gold, and guess it will be abnormal price.

I am stuck and do not know what to do and what is going on. Must be something between "hobbyist" and "professional" PCB fab markets, with ENIG being for hobby, and when it comes to properly gold-plated edge connector is becomes professional, with totally different pricing level.

If you have been making your designs with edge connectors, how did you manufacture them, and what is your opinion the best way for their finishing for durability (e.g. 500 insertions)?

Comment: 41 USD for 8400 mm² doesn't sound expensive to me, if anything, relatively cheap for PCB manufacturers; you might be a bit spoiled by the nice cheap Chinese and oshpark PCB shuttle services :)  yeah, gold fingers aren't standard cheap-market features, so I think you might be out of luck. However, 500 insertions: That sounds like you don't want gold fingers at all? is changing the design to something else still possible?

Comment: Without gold fingers, ENIG only, board is quoted at $3. And the hard gold to be applied to space of 500 mm2. I have edge connector, and the board must be inserted into it. What do you propose?

Comment: getting rid of the finger concept, and using a connector component, to be honest. 500 insertions mean you need a good process, and at 50 pcs, no chance that's going to be cheap. If you were to manufacture 10000 PCIe cards, or a million nintendo cartridges or anything, that would be different.

Comment: The reason why an ENIG board without any special processing is cheap is that you can slap that board, and a couple others, onto a single panel, and process it as one, with the last step being the milling, and then a single manual step, isolating different customer's boards and putting them into shipping boxes. With gold fingers, there's a) additional bevel milling necessary, b) a very labour-intense step of taking the PCB, and dipping it into an electroplating bath, and often even another milling step after. For that to even work you need an engineer to look at your board files;

Comment: your 3$ boards are "let the customer upload their file, let our least-cost labor put that file on a panel, and then let the machine do the same as for every other customer". See the difference?

Comment: Got it re:process. You almost correct - these are 50 of almost nintendo cartridges. Unable to replace edge connector with anything else.

Comment: I'd seriously consider living with ENIG's wear then...

Comment: You want "Hard Gold" plating.    https://www.7pcb.com/blog/hard-gold-plating.php